# How to detect double tap in spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I use this touch.tapCount in touchesBegan and try to print the value but it never return 2.

Any idea why? It can be 1,3,,5,7,9, .... but not 2,4,6,8,10, ...

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


    if let touch = touches.first {
        //print(touch.tapCount)
        if ((touch.tapCount) == 1) {
            player.animatedPlayer()
            jump = true
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this code working fine, try `(touch.tapCount) == 2` n check

Comment: Thank Pratik, but it is not :(

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089619/swift-skspritenode-detect-tap-doubletap-longpress

Comment: @BehrouzPooladrag Hi, system still can not detect the double tap. Is there any property need to be set-up for double tap?

Comment: check your touch.tapCount data if it increased, it would be ok, and you can run your function after that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use UITapGestureRecognizer to handle tapEvent.
the numberOfTapsRequired property make this detect DoubleTap only

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     var tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
     #selector(self.handleTapGesture(gesture:)))
     tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
     self.scene?.view?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
 }

 @objc func handleTapGesture(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    // do something here
 }
```

Hope helpfull!